# Watching for file changes with StatReloader

Tags: django, docker

I try to use docker in order to make the process of launching my django app automatically. I built the image, then executed the command `docker run <image>`. But everything I see is the line `Watching for file changes with StatReloader` and nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?